# @on_message.error AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'error' in discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

```py
import discord

from discord.ext import commands

from discord.ext.commands import Bot


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "/")

@bot.event

async def on_message(message):
    
mm = message.mentions[2]

    await message.channel.send(mm)

@on_message.error

async  def on_command(ctx,error):

    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.message.author.mention}check")




bot.run('TOKEN_HERE')
```

Comment: What did you want `@on_message.error` to do?

Comment: Need a more clear question here.

Answer (score 0):

`on_message` is not a command, it's an event. You need to handle the errors in the event itself, you can't add an error handler.